# Do indexing metadata in amazon elasticsearch works with the encrypted content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, encryption

**Scenario**

I have Full text search requirement which can search inside the document.  I am uploading documents in s3 bucket and encrypting it using envelope encryption.
Can we do full text search in encrypted document(in S3 bucket).    If yes what are the rest API(NodeJS API) for the same.

```
Example => bucket1 =>Encrypted content in the files

bucket1/abc.pdf
bucket1/def.doc
bucket1/ghi.txt
```

and I want to search text like `"I am from planet earth"` in the above files.
I want in result file name(s) with above text.

**Solution**

I am reading following article:

[aws article here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/)

[encryption of data at rest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/encryption-at-rest.html)

**Problem**

- Will it works if s3 bucket data is encrypted?
- What will be the best solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not search inside documents, you need to index the content of the documents inside elasticsearch to be able to perform searchs, it also does not support search on encrypted data, the data needs to be stored in clear text.

What you can do is configure SSL/TLS and authentication on Elasticsearch, so you only will be able to make requests if you use the correct certificate and a username and password.

Comment: Do Elasticsearch store data also as text? If yes then it will be security issue because I am encrypting files data so that it will be safe in the aws cloud.

Comment: Elasticsearch does not encrypt or decrypt anything, if you want to be able to search for a string or word in a document, you need to index the content of the document in elastic in plain text. You can index the encrypted content or just some fields, but you will only be able to search for the encrypted value.

Comment: Cannot we sync s3 bucket to AWS elasticsearch using lambda function. I was reading this article:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/